# Laravel, get relation row instead of id

Tags: laravel, relation

I want to get author row instead of author_id. I could this with add collection and change one by one but has Laravel any function for this? Well, I want make this one line
Can i use something like this

```
Book::where('id',$bid)->with('author')->first('author_id AS author'); //Changes only coulmn name :(
```

**model**

```
public function author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::class,'id','author_id');
    }
```

**query**

```
Book::where('id',$bid)->with('author')->first()
```

**Output**

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Book 1",
    "author_id": 3,
    "category_id": 2,
    "level_id": 1,
    "book_language_id": 1,
    "book_length": 0,
    "img": "book1.png",
    "summary": "Summary 1",
    "rate_avg": "2.75",
    "created_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-03-04T18:52:28.000000Z",
    "author": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Author 3",
        "created_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z"
    }
}
```

**Want**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Book 1",
    "author": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Author 3",
        "created_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z"
    },
    "category_id": 2,
    "level_id": 1,
    "book_language_id": 1,
    "book_length": 0,
    "img": "book1.png",
    "summary": "Summary 1",
    "rate_avg": "2.75",
    "created_at": "2022-03-04T18:46:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-03-04T18:52:28.000000Z",
    
}
```

Comment: the output and what you want seem to be the same, just different order of fields, if i understood correctly, you want only to get the author row ("author": {...}) right?

Comment: Exactly, I want this

Comment: you can add `public $hidden = ['author_id']` to your model. changing the order is not needed because its a object and not a list.

Comment: Logical :), thanks. Well, is it possible to change the way I want? Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

in your query

```
Book::where('id',$bid)->with('author')->first()
```

you are getting the book that has that id and you are eager loading the author relation, so in order to get the author you have to access the author field:

```
Book::where('id',$bid)->with('author')->first()->author
```

Comment: but your query only gets author info

Comment: the author row shouldn't be the author info?

Answer (score 0):

As I said I can this with collection like this:

```
$b=Book::where('id',$bid)->with('author')->first();

                    $book=collect([
                        'id'=>$b->id,
                        'name'=>$b->name,
                        'author'=>$b->author,
                        'category_id'=>$b->category_id,
                        'level_id'=>$b->level_id,
                        'book_language_id'=>$b->book_language_id,
                        'book_length'=>$b->book_length,
                        'summary'=>$b->summary,
                        'rate_avg'=>$b->rate_avg,
                    ]);
```

But this method seems unnecessary

Comment: This example makes no sense, you making the same object assigning 'autohor' => $b->author, Do You need something like 'author' => $b->author->name ?

Comment: You're right, ordering objects doesn't matter I forgot this

Answer (score 0):

In your example the only difference between the **output** and **what you want** is `"author_id": 3`, as been deleted.

So if you don't want a column or rename a column, you need to use `->select` and take all the field you want. And you can also rename with something like that

```
-> select(DB::raw('author_id as auhtor'), 'books.*')
```